# JSONP not displaying data in HTML

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently experimenting JSONP data using native Javascript. I am trying to get the data to display. How ever i am receiving a syntax error. `Unexpected token :` As far as i am aware i follow the correct steps into in order gather data. Below is a snippet of my code. [Link to JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/29eajsjm/2/)

```
<script src="http://linkToMyJSONDetails"></script>
```

JS

```
function (data) {
  var showStops = '';

 for (var i = 0; i < data.markers.length; i++) {
 showStops += '<div class="stops">';
 showStops += '<h3>' + data.markers[i].smsCode + '</h3>';
 showStops += '<h1>' + data.markers[i].name + '</h1>';
 showStops += '</div>';
 }

  document.getElementById('bus-stops').innerHTML = showStops;

 }
```

Comment: `function (data)` You need to give a name to the function. Also where are you calling this function? Just by adding the `<script>` add you can't access it using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things.
First: Add a callback: (Scroll to the right, since your link is a bit long)

```
http://digitaslbi-id-test.herokuapp.com/bus-stops?northEast=51.52783450,-0.04076115&southWest=51.51560467,-0.10225884&callback=someFunction
                                                                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Second: Define the callback:

```
// same function name as the callback in the jsonp url
function someFunction(data) { 
  var showStops = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.markers.length; i++) {
    showStops += '<div class="stops">';
    showStops += '<h3>' + data.markers[i].smsCode + '</h3>';
    showStops += '<h1>' + data.markers[i].name + '</h1>';
    showStops += '</div>';
  }

  document.getElementById('bus-stops').innerHTML = showStops;

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29eajsjm/4/
Make sure the function is defined before calling the jsonp.

Comment: Thanks for this VERY helpful, i didn't realise how simple is it.

Answer (score 0):

you have not mentioned the function name.

insead of

```
function (data) {
```

use

```
var myFn = function (data) {

};
```

or

```
function myFN(data) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all validate the json you are getting from your function at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com).